# how to display a div at center top of the page

Tags: html, css

How to display a div at center top position of the page, which need to be work under all size of monitors using CSS.

Mainly I get issues on IE, where not aligned properly.

Comment: The answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498552/horizontal-and-vertical-center-text-in-html/2857692#2857692

Answer (score 3):

For margin: 0px auto;
to work width needs to be provided

style:

```
div#center 
{
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="center">content</div>
```

Comment: Why do you use the unit "px" for the attribute value "0"? That's not neccessary and usually omitted.

Comment: typo, apologies. Typed in 10px at first as an example, then I've noticed OP asked for top of the page. Will leave it for reference though :D

Comment: accepted :D I was just surprised because everybody else here was using it... so it doesn't seem well established?!

Answer (score 0):

CSS

> ```
> div
> {
> margin : 0px auto;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you comparing the rendering in both IE and another browser by switching back and forth? If so, you might be noticing a shift because of the scroll bar. IE reserves the space for the scrollbar, while browsers such as Firefox only show the window scroll when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

div#center 
{
 width: 300px;
 margin: 0px auto;
}

not working on IE...