# Horizontal and vertical center text in html

Tags: css, html

I have a div with a background image that needs to be centered horizontally and vertically. On top of that image, I also want to display a 1-line text, also centered horizontally and vertically.

I managed to get the image centered, but the text is not centered vertically. I thought vertical-align:middle would do the trick.

Here's the code I have:

```
<div style="background: url('background.png') no-repeat center; width:100%; height:100%; text-align:center;">
   <div style="color:#ffffff; text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;" >
       Some text here.
   </div>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

---

Workaround: I actually got this to work by using a table. (I'll probably be cursed to hell by the HTML community.) Is there any significant reason not to use this btw? I'm still interested in the solution using divs though.

```
 <table width="100%" height="100%">
   <tr>
     <td align="center" style="background: url('background.png') no-repeat center; color:#ffffff;">Some text here.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The use of tables for anything that is not tabular data has a *reputation* of triggering accessibility issues. However, such issues are only triggered if the table contents break upon *linearization*.
There is a trick to test linearization: add `table, tr, td { display: block; }` to a testing CSS sheet: if the content remains usable/readable (despite the layout breaking) your table serializes ok; if it becomes entirely unusable, assistive technologies will have trouble to parse your table. In the case of a single-cell table, linearization can never get broken, so you should be fine.

Comment: @Christophe Herreman: "Is there any significant reason not to use this btw?" In my opinion NO, there is NOT a significant reason not to use a table in this case except for auto gratification in solving a problem. For this specific task using a table is even probably a more cross-browsers solution rather than using CSS.

Comment: @Marco Demaio There is a significant reason. It's less accessible to those who are visually impaired and use screen readers.

Answer (score 4):

Horizontal centering of a block element is traditionally done this way:

```
div.inner { margin: 0 auto; }
```

**Note:** the above won't work with IE in quirks mode so **always** put a `DOCTYPE` at the top of your document to force it into standards compliant mode.

Vertical centering is much more tedious. See [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)

Comment: the inner div has to specify a certain width to get centered i.e. "width: 300px;"

Answer (score 2):

there is no direct vertical centering for div content in CSS, however there are indirect ways of achieving it.
http://phrogz.net/CSS/vertical-align/index.html

also many similar questions in SO. [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: The 'correct' way to do it depends on how much text you are going to have. If you know what's going to be there, then it becomes much easier.

Comment: I only have 1 line of text to show.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have to use only one line of text and parent div has fixed height use line-height property. Suppose parent height is 500px then use CSS line-height: 500px;  for text.

Answer (score 0):

Without using javascript (ala something like thickbox, etc. for positioning photos/captions centered), the closest I could come to was this:

```
<body style="height:200px; min-height:800px;">
   <div style="background: url('background.png') no-repeat center; height:100%;">
      <div style="text-align: center; position:relative; top:50%; color:#fff;">
         Some text here.
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
```

Note that I had to specify some sort of height for the container (in this case the BODY but it could also have been applied to the wrapper DIV I think). In Explorer 6, you can set the BODY height to 100% but in Firefox this doesn't work and probably won't work in other modern browsers.

**EDIT:**

Found a better solution:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {height:100%;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="background: url('background.png') no-repeat center; height:100%;">
        <div style="text-align: center; position:relative; top:50%; color:#fff;">
            Some text here.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get **VERTICAL centering**, I would suggest to use a table inside the DIV (as suggested by Cletus above other ways might be tedious).

```
div.centered table {margin: 0 auto;} /* no width needs to be specified for table */
div.centered table td {vertical-align: middle;} /* replace this with vertical-align: top; to disable vertical centering */


<!-- borders added only to help understanding -->
<div class="centered" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
    <table style="border: 1px solid #ff0000;">
       <tbody>
          <tr><td>
             Some text here
          </td></tr>
       </tbody>
    </table> 
</div>
```

If you are only interested in **HORIZONTAL centering** (no vertical) you can use only DIV:

```
div.centered div {margin: 0 auto; width: 300px;} /* some width MUST be specified to center a DIV. */

<!-- borders added only to help understanding -->
<div class="centered" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc;">
    <div style="border: 1px solid #ff0000;">
       Some text here
    </div> 
</div>
```

As you might have noticed in order to horizontally align a DIV inside a DIV you also **need to specify a fixed width for the inner DIV**. This might be somehow not what you want to do, so it might be easier to use always the 1st solution (the one with TABLE) and simply remove the "vertical-align: middle;" when you want to get only horizontal centering.

I tested this using document with:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

on IE7, FF 3.6, SAFARI 4.0.4